# Layer switcher control and WMS layer control: How to set in which control you want to show the WMS layers in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, layer-switcher

I'm using the example http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.wmscapabilities.html?lon=2.349572&lat=48.853266&z=16&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgeoservices.brgm.fr%2Fgeologie%3Flanguage%3Dfre%26&layer=SUSCEPTIBILITE_AMIANTE_1M
for controlling WMS layers.

I have the LayerSwitcher just like the URL example, to show WMS layers from different sources. But I have another one that I use, for our inner layers.

What happens is that when you add a WMS layer, it is adding to both controls and I would like it to be only one. How can I restrict, every time I add a WMS layer, I only add it to a LayerSwitcher ?

[EDIT]
I have two controls: Figure 1 (Inner layers - fixed) and Figure 2 (WMS Layers),
where the user can choose a service URL and added as layers.

When I add a WMS layer (Figure 2), that same layer is being added
on the control in Figure 1 (Figure 3) and I don't want it placed on both controls.

[image]

Code: layerSwitcher showing WMS layers and WMS control

```
var layerSwitcher2 = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher2({ 
    trash: true, 
    extent: true,
    collapsed: false,
});

map.addControl(layerSwitcher2)
  
var cap = new ol.control.WMSCapabilities({ 
    // target: $('.options').get(0),
    target: document.body,
    srs: ['EPSG:2154'],
    cors: true,
    popupLayer: true,
    placeholder: 'Escolha o serviço WMS ou digite a URL...',
    title: 'Serviços WMS',
    searchLabel: 'Busca',
    optional: 'token',
    services: {
      'UFABC': 'https://geoservicos.inde.gov.br/geoserver/UFABC/ows',
      'OSM': 'https://wms.openstreetmap.fr/wms',
      'Datageo': 'http://datageo.ambiente.sp.gov.br/geoserver/datageo/ows?SERVICE=WMS&',
      'IBGE': 'https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&',
    },
    // Show trace in the console
    trace: true
});
map.addControl(cap);

cap.on('load', function(e) {
    map.addLayer(e.layer);
    e.layer.set('legend', e.options.data.legend);
});
```

Other layers group, here I don't want it to show wms layers

```
var overlays = new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'Temas/Assuntos',
    fold: 'open',
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false, //não mostrar no controle layer switcher ol-ext  
    layers: [tema_santo_andre,
            tema_aspecto_socioeconomico,
            tema_assistencia_social, 
            tema_conselho,
            tema_craisa,
            tema_cultura,
            tema_defesa_civil,
            tema_educacao, 
            tema_esporte,
            tema_habitacao,
            tema_infraestrutura_urbana, 
            tema_legislacao,
            tema_meio_ambiente,
            tema_mobilidade,
            tema_planejamento,
            tema_pessoa_deficiencia,
            tema_saude,
            tema_seguranca_publica, 
            tema_servico_cidadao,
            tema_turismo,  
            tema_limites,]
});
map.addLayer(overlays)
```

Comment: What is `ol.control.LayerSwitcher2`? Where does it come from?

Comment: It's the `ol.control.LayerSwitcher` ol-ext, I renamed it because I already have another type of layer switcher control. It is the control used in this example [link] (http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.wmscapabilities.html?lon=2.349572&lat=48.853266&z=16&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgeoservices.brgm.fr%2Fgeologie%3Flanguage%3Dfre%26&layer=SUSCEPTIBILITE_AMIANTE_1M)

Comment: There is only one layer switcher control in the code above. Where is the second one? Its also not clear what should be displayed in which control, since you are using option `displayInLayerSwitcher: false` for `overlays` which prevents display in any control. Please edit your question and clarify this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add code for the other layer switcher.